# How to define a timeout for Apache Airflow DAGs?

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.10.2 but Airflow seems to ignore the timeout I've set for the DAG.

I'm setting a timeout period for the DAG using the `dagrun_timeout` parameter (e.g. 20 seconds) and I've got a task which takes 2 mins to run, but Airflow marks the DAG as successful!

```py
args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'provide_context': True,
}

dag = DAG(
    'test_timeout',
     schedule_interval=None,
     default_args=args,
     dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=20),
)

def this_passes(**kwargs):
    return

def this_passes_with_delay(**kwargs):
    time.sleep(120)
    return

would_succeed = PythonOperator(
    task_id='would_succeed',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=this_passes,
    email=to,
)

would_succeed_with_delay = PythonOperator(
    task_id='would_succeed_with_delay',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=this_passes_with_delay,
    email=to,
)

would_succeed >> would_succeed_with_delay
```

No error messages are thrown. Am I using an incorrect parameter?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As stated in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L138-L141):

```
:param dagrun_timeout: specify how long a DagRun should be up before
    timing out / failing, so that new DagRuns can be created. The timeout
    is only enforced for scheduled DagRuns, and only once the
    # of active DagRuns == max_active_runs.
```

so this might be expected behavior as you set `schedule_interval=None`. Here, the idea is rather to make sure a scheduled DAG won't last forever and block subsequent run instances.

Now, you may be interested in the [`execution_timeout`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L167-L168) available in all operators.
For example, you could set a 60s timeout on your `PythonOperator` like this:

```py
would_succeed_with_delay = PythonOperator(task_id='would_succeed_with_delay',
                            dag=dag,
                            execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=60),
                            python_callable=this_passes_with_delay,
                            email=to)
```

Comment: Thank you, Lucas. I will try that now.

Comment: Well written answer, +1, but I think you misspelled "execution_timeout" as "execution_timout".

I was looking for the execution_timeout variable, so you helped me fi,ne sir

Comment: @VendableFall A bit hilarious that a comment about a typo has a typo.